# OpenSSL: How to match if certificate and private key matches

Tags: ssl, openssl

I've an certificate and a p12 private key.

I need to check if both match:

```
$ openssl rsa -modulus -noout -in visor.p12 | openssl md5
unable to load Private Key
139755626676672:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY

$ openssl x509 –noout –modulus –in EC_SECPUBLIC.cer | openssl md5 
x509: Unknown parameter –noout
x509: Use -help for summary.
(stdin)= d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You received the private key as *.p12 keystore file, so you need to extract the private key first. You can use this command to get the private key in PEM encoding: openssl pkcs12 -in visor.p12 -nocerts -out privateKey.pem

Comment: I agree with Michael Fehr.  I've also noticed that the "-in <filename>" needs to be the first argument to avoid that "x509: Unknown parameter" error... so for your second command, try: openssl x509 –in EC_SECPUBLIC.cer –noout –modulus | openssl md5